# WIX: Run MSI repair mode in Elevated mode

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I have a WIX MSI and it is installing sucessfully . But I need to provide elevated privilege during the Repair mode. How it is achived using WIX

Answer (score 0):

Resolved it myself by adding the following property

```
<Property Id="MSIUSEREALADMINDETECTION" Value="1" />
```